# How to load a image into dynamically created imageview from a URL in android?

Tags: android, uiimageview

I have dynamically created imageview in my app. I tried to load images from URL. But it does not working. I have tried with many methods, and my currently used code is

```
 try {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL("http://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png").getContent());
            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But image is not loaded. What is mistake?

Comment: Use image libraries like Glide or Picasso or Universal image loader for loading images. It's much better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try piccaso library:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

//Loading image from below url into imageView

```
Picasso.with(this).load("https://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png").into(imageView);
```

//change url
take permission in your mainifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

for resize:

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("https://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png").resize(100, 100).into(i1);
```

Comment: error:Cannot find the variable Picasso. i got this error while compling . need to use any package?

Comment: you need to add piccaso library. use this jar in your project picasso-2.5.2

Comment: @bala check this link: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.picasso/picasso/2.5.2

Comment: ,i have added . but till same problem

Comment: just wait i will chk it in my project

Comment: post your logcat @bala

Comment: yeah its working. no error. but image is not load or display in imageview.

Comment: try {
            Picasso.with(this).load("http://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png").into(img);
        }catch (Exception e){

        }finally {
        }

Comment: this is what i am using  to test. what is wrong @Damini Mehra

Comment: try this code: i1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("https://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png").into(i1);

Comment: any idea about compressing the image size?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Universal Image Loader**

UIL aims to provide a powerful, flexible and highly customizable instrument for image loading, caching and displaying. It provides a lot of configuration options and good control over the image loading and caching process.

```
// Load image, decode it to Bitmap and display Bitmap in ImageView (or any other view 
//  which implements ImageAware interface)
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView);
```

Reference Link - https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 0):

Use library to load images from url 
1. Glide library  Refer here:http://coderzpassion.com/android-working-glide-image-loader-library/  
2. Picasso library Refer here:http://coderzpassion.com/android-use-picasso-image-loader-library/ 
3. Volley Library Refer here:http://coderzpassion.com/android-working-volley-library/

Answer (score 0):

Use Simple AQuery library for image loading from internet

```
// AQuery object
private AQuery aquery;

aquery = new AQuery(context);

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

aquery.id(imageView).image("Your image url ",false,false);

Add permission to manifest file

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```