# When select a image, its link is saved in the realtime database, how can I display image in ImageView?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

The user can select an image and install it on his profile, when selecting an image, the url gets into the realtime database line, how do I display this image in ImageView?[image]

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Uri uri = data.getData();
    images.setImageURI(uri);


    final StorageReference reference = storage.getReference()
            .child("image");

    reference.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            reference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    database.getReference("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("image")
                            .setValue(uri.toString()).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void unused) {


                                }
                            });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250983/how-to-load-a-image-into-dynamically-created-imageview-from-a-url-in-android or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58584600/how-to-dynamically-load-images-from-a-url-into-imageview-from-a-viewmodel-in-kot?

Comment: @Frank I translated the code to java, but this method did not work

Comment: @Frank so I use picasso, but how do I upload a specific url for a specific user

Comment: images.setImageURI(Uri.parse(url));

Comment: @blackapps I'm a beginner, Can you describe the code?

Comment: That is all. You said you save the link. The link is the uri. Or better the string value of the uri. The url in that code line is the string value of the uri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed picasso to glide and it worked